# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate (null)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, aggregate, nspredicate

I am getting this Unsupported predicate error, while trying to instantiate a 
    NSFetchedResultsController with an aggregate Predicate.

My Coredata structure looks like this - There is a PurchaseDetails Entity which has n number of Payment Entity (One to many relationship). Each Payment has a type, for eg.Cash, Cheque , Other etc. Now I need to get the list of all the PurchaseDetails where Payment.type = Cash.

The NSPredicate looks like this: `@"ALL payments.type = 'cash'"`

Are we not supposed to use `ALL` ?
The predicate isn't crashing on creation rather it crash while executing the fetch request.

But the same fetch request works fine when used separately without using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. They both wont work together ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use `ALL` if payments is a to-many relationship. Note that this means that every single payment's `type` will be `@"cash"`. If you just want at least one cash payment, use `ANY`.

The `(null)` in the error message hints at something else though. Did you attach the predicate to the fetch request?

Also, did you try to set `cache:nil`in your fetched results controller? The FRC could be the reason you get stale results.

Comment: Yeah I need only the PurchaseDetails where all payments are of type 'cash'. It crashes right at `[controller performFetch:&error]` and the  fetch request is also correct. Everything works fine if I replace it with `ANY` but it is not the indented predicate.

Comment: So it maybe does "not work" because there is a payment where the type is not `cash` or not set. -- Also, with FRC, there is often an cache problem. Try setting `cache:nil` when initializing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have made sure that the cache is nil. I dint got your first point.

Comment: First point: I mean, check your data. Maybe the predicate is correct, but the data does not contain what you expect.